# I need assistance rendering my website on larger screens

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need assistance rendering my website on larger screen (1680 x 1050) & (1920 1080)

I can say the website is fine on other screen sizes but somehow the height didn't conform same way on these screens (1680 x 1050) & (1920 1080) and some of the page contents over-lapsed.

This is the page [HERE](http://deckard.rf.gd) and to verify my complaint if you don't have such screen size, just go [Here](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) and type the deckard.rf.gd and see what  mean or us [This](http://www.techiepool.com/responsive-check/).

Any and all help or pointer would really help.

Comment: You can use `@media query` in CSS to fix that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Use bootstrap grid: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212).

Comment: Like @VladimirJovanović suggested, you should use *media queries* to help style your elements so that they are displayed well on different screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I have tried using media query to the the process but it doesn't seem to be working.                                                     @media only screen and (max-width:1200px) {
    .acidjs-horizontal-accordion {
        width: 1000px;
        margin-left: -6%;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

The site uses hard values for elements, making them less responsive. Try using `vh` and `calc` to ensure that heights are responsive to screen size.

It seems that the site already attempts to be responsive, thought it's rather bloated for such a small site. You may want to reduce some of the resources used and clean up your code just a bit.

You may want something like this: https://codepen.io/jobaelish/full/mKbxLa/

Answer (score -1):

You can use **@media** in css. First of all you need to add your logo or **Favicon**